# Should I reuse virtual when overriding in a sub-subclass?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know I don't need to declare an overriding function in a subclass as `virtual`. But if I'm using a virtual function in a sub-subclass do I need to declare the subclass function as `virtual`?

```
struct Base
{
    virtual int foo();
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual int foo() override
    {
       // ...
    }
};

struct DoubleDerived : Derived
{
    int foo() override
    {
       // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [Core guideline C.128](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override) that states:

```
Virtual functions should specify exactly one of virtual, override, or final.
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to, the function is virtual anyways, but it makes it unquestionably clear. Previously (before `override` was available) you could override some function and then if the function was changed in base class your derived class wouldn't override it anymore and the code would compile without any issues. Your function in derived class wouldn't override anything and would become non-virtual.

With [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) compiler will prevent this kind of mistakes and the function cannot magically become non-virtual if base is changed. In other words, if [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) or [final](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) is used, it's implied that the function is [virtual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual), it would be compilation error otherwise.

Comment: A virtual function is stored as a pointer in a class's vtable and called indirectly from there. Any half-way decent compiler should notice that a derived function is virtual but it doesn't hurt to make it clear.

Comment: @Mike yes, does my answer contradict that in any way?

Comment: No, just giving a little more detail as to what's going on in the background. Understanding what's going on under the hood tends to make things clearer. Besides, a small compiler could, legally, generate a static call to classname::function () which just happened to share a name with a virtual base-class.